# array_keys returns Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have this function

```
protected function insert($data){
        $data['datecreated'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        echo "array_keys(data) = ".$data['datecreated'];
        var_dump($data);
        echo array_keys($data);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->table_name} (".  array_keys($data).")"; 
        $sql.= " VALUES ('";
        $sql.=implode("','", $data);
        $sql.=")";
        $this->execute($sql);
        $this->last_id = mysql_insert_id();
    }
```

when i read the `array_keys($data)` it returns 'Array' not the key 
i call it like this `$this->insert(array());` why is that ? 
EDIT : 
this is the output

```
array_keys(data) = 2012-05-18 04:44:46array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } ["datecreated"]=> string(19) "2012-05-18 04:44:46" } Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Tamara/model/dbTable.php on line 105
INSERT INTO account (Array) VALUES ('Array','2012-05-18 04:44:46)You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2012-05-18 04:44:46)' at line 1
```

Comment: `array_keys( )` returns an array, not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

array_keys returns an array with all the keys.
You need to implode that aswell

```
implode(',', array_keys($data));
```

Edit:
And you might want to take a look at this part

```
$sql.=implode("','", $data);
$sql.=")";
```

You need need a starting and trailing `'`.

Comment: thanks alot dude i upvote the question but to check it i need 7 minutes as they told me

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to sanitize your input with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://co.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or look into using [PDO](http://co.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)/[MySQLi](http://co.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with prepared statements to protect your app against SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `implode(',', array_keys($data))` since [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) returns an array containing all the keys - but you want a comma-separated string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->table_name} (".implode(',', array_keys($data)).")";
```

By the way, I hope that the values in `$data` are already escaped. If not, replace `implode("','", $data)` with `implode("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data))`

Comment: My recommendation is to never assume that anything is pre escaped, it almost always results in some one missing to escape somewhere.

Comment: Indeed, escaping should happen at the place where the query is built (or even better, it shouldn't be necessary due to the use of prepared statement or parametrized queries). But while double-escaping is "safe" it'd result in ugly backslashes in the actual data that is stored.

Comment: True which is why escaping should (when as noted is needed) always be done only when building, and never stored in escaped version within the code. This is extra work but worth every bit, byte and second it takes when it comes to security.